# How to verify if two databases are identical using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, database

I have two databases in two networks. I want to check one against another for to see table definition mismatches. I have database definition scripts of both databases. Is there any built-in function in SQL Server to achieve this.?

All the configurations in database servers are similar. The server version is SQL Server 12.0.2.

Update: I know there are text comparison tools, and I use beyond compare.

Comment: You don't even mention what SQL engine you use.

Comment: If you need to know if tables are the same, you can query informational schema like SELECT tablename
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE database = 'dbA'    EXCEPT   SELECT tablename
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE database = 'dbB' of course you can do same for list of columns. The syntax depends on the sql environment you use of course. Anyway, check EXCEPT syntax for your sql to get results that are in one data set and not in the other

Comment: @juergend question updated.

Comment: Absolutely any text comparison tool? For example WinDiff. If this is SQL Server then I suggest that you download SQL Server Data Tools and use schema compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the database definition scripts the easy way is to use diff on the UNIX (or Mac) command line, or windiff in Windows (see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/does-windiff-exec-available-in-windows-10-64-bit/624fb262-7cba-49bd-b02e-74814a4d11b6?auth=1).

Otherwise you can use a database design tool.  There are many available but they all cost a lot more than using diff.